# Quick way to generalize( maybe modeling / extract / summarize) the recursive part of thinking pattern

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Thanks for help. I am new to algorithm. Currently I am preparing questions which are mostly from Site like LeetCode or Careercup. One important area I find useful is recursive programming which I have tried very hard but still can not get it.

For example, the question of generating all permutation of a string with duplicated character. I can think about each step to do it recursively as human, but when I need to figure out how to organize the structure of the recursive part, then here comes the problem.

Suppose we have drawn the whole procedure chart. After that Could anyone give me some detail explanation for how to quickly identify which part can be extracted into the recursive unit( rules to extract out that pattern part ) OR explanation how to identfy which part should put in current recursive function body, which part should use as parameter passed to next round recursive function calling.

I may not be able to fully express my question, so if anyone answer this question, you can just give the way( or each detail step or thinking pattern or any skill ) how you modeling this question and why think in that way in terms of recursive function.

I do not believe this is only my personal question, there must be a lot of beginners having same thing, I hope we can share our idea about how to learn algorithm smartly and quickly rather than coding a lot questions without efficient progress. I even think we can set post set(like a cookbook) for how to build thinking pattern and skill to solve these algorithm question.

Comment: in current state is your question unanswerable. 1. the title is misleading to computer learning systems (like AI) 2. the recursion topic is so broad that you can fill entire books about it. The best way to learn it is by specific examples and comparison between iteration (like for loop) and recursion. This site is not suited for this kind of stuff instead you should post questions for speciic problems like you want to solve some specific problem by recursion...

Comment: I recommend you to google basic problems in booth iterative and recursive form like factorial, Hanoi towers, etc... there are a lot of question even here on SO. when you hit a specific example you do not understand then post that as a Question (if not posted already) and that will be answerable. Wery good for beginer thinking advancmets are `Project Euler` ... try it, ... it is constructed in manner so you incrementaly add knowledge to see the bigger picture behind advanced algoritmic problems

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for reply. I do have put an example in my question which is the permutation of string with dup character. I wonder could you give your thinking step for that question(especially how to decide the parameters of the recursive function)? I guess my trouble is how to extract detail step into coding structure pattern.

Comment: How would you have drawn the "*whole procedure chart*" without knowing the recursion? Did you implement it as a loop, and now want to go to a recursive definition?

Comment: @Kuan I tried to get you an example of your recursion. (added answer) btw you really should change the Title of your question

Comment: @Spektre Thanks so much for such a detail reply. Could you suggest any title of my question?

Comment: @Bergi By "whole procedure chart" I mean I choose a simple example and draw each step of the permutation. I think I have trouble with finding which part is the recursive body.(by another way, I have trouble with how to find a thinking pattern to modeling base case.)

Comment: You mean, each step of the construction process of the permutations? Typically, "each step" is a recursive function call.

Comment: Hm, maybe you can post the chart you've drawn?

Comment: @Bergi I guess My problem right now is how to identify which tasks should put as the recursive function body and how to organize their order to make sure they works well recursive call. Also How to plan what should be use as the parameter to be passed to next round recursion

Comment: That's complicated, as there are many different possibilities to do that. In general, you would think of "stages" of your process, where a stage only depends on the function input and the result of the previous stage. Can you identify groups of steps as such a stage? Then put them in the function body, and make each stage a recursive call. Without knowing your model of thought (on the permutations), it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for reply. How about just use the example I post here, the permutation of "abcc" to illustrate how did you think and why you think in that way?

Comment: The typical recursion over a list is so-called "primitive recursion": Derive the permutations of `abcc` from the permutations of `bcc` - by inserting the `a` in each of them at each possible position (and the base case is the empty list, typically trivial). Admittedly, dealing with duplicates is not that easy in this approach. A different way to construct all permutations of `abcc` would be to prepend `a` to every permutation of `bcc`, prepend a `b` to every permutatio of `acc`, and prepend a `c` to every permutation of `abc`. Can you spot the pattern?

Comment: Which language are you developing in? I know it's not exactly relevant for the question that asks about the generic practice, but I could give you examples in a language that you understand.

Comment: @Bergi I can understand Javascript and Java, so either version is appreciated. But more important thing I may need is the explanation when you modeling this question,  How you think about each step and what factors lead you into think in that way.

Comment: @kuan 1. for the title I would use something like How to develop/construct recursive functions for string permutation generators? most definetly loose the thinking pattern part... 2. my experience for recursive programing is that you will be just slowed down by algorithm charts as first step before programing you need to now how to describe and achieve the goal you want only then start coding. you need always breakpoint/trace debug the recursion because is easily bugged without any visible cause at first look the debug will usually reveal the problem. On chart you can not do any of this.

Comment: @kuan recursion is used when the task at hand is separable to subtask of lower magnitude of the same sort. for example 5 disc hanoi towers are solvable by 4 disc + trivial movement, 4 disc case is solvable by 3 disk and movement and so on until you have just 1 disc left (which is stop condition) the same goes for string generation N char string is solvable by N-1 string + single character .... when your task is divisible like that then the function(N-1) is the recursive part. as tail is used the N-1 plus all data needed for the task (data which is changing between steps)

Answer (score 0):

well for generating all permutation of a string of length `N`

- you need N nested for loops which will generate all the possibilities through alphabet
- you can look at it as incrementation of a number but instead of digits you have characters
- so 3 char words lowercase without interpunction will look like this:

  ```
  const int N=3; // target word size
  char w[N+1];   // generated word
  int i;
  w[N]=0;        // end of word
  i=0; for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++){
  i++; for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++){
  i++; for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++){
  // here w[] contains generated word so do something with it
  }i--;
  }i--;
  }
  ```
- as you can see the code is simple and straightforward
- but it is hardcoded to match N=3 and can not be changed during runtime
- unless you use self changing code ... which is not very welcome in current higher level languages and more suited for assembly only
- but if you rewrite this to a recursion all the problems will dissapear
- of coarse new ones will surface like heap/stack trashing ...

Porting from iteration to recursion

- recursion parameter is like index in for loop
- it has to lower its functional magnitude so it stops in finite time
- and the recursion must contain some sort of stop condition
- the N character word generation can be rewrite as
- `genere_word(N)=genere_word(N-1)+generate_char();`
- so you can write function that generate all 1 char words
- and with recursion you can achieve N character word
- the recursion tail (operands) can be the actual generated word `w`
- and the layer of recursion (actual generated character position `i`)
- of coarse `i` character generation does not change the `i-1` character or any previous
- so  we do not need to throw the `w` on stack and can leave it as pointer or as global variable
- so we really need just `i` as a tail
- something like this:

  ```
  char w[1024]={0};           // big enough buffer
  void _generate(int i)       // recursion call
      {
      // stop conditions
      if (i==0) for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++)   // if first character then the word is complete so no recursion
          {
          // here w[] contains generated word so do something with it
          }
      else      for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++)   // else
          {
          // not all characters are genered yet so recursively generete next one
          _generate(i-1);
          }
      }
  void generate(int N)        // main call
      {
      // here you can create w[N+1] dynamically instead
      if (N<    0) N=   0;    // avoid access violations on invalid N
      if (N>=1024) N=1023;    // avoid access violations on invalid N
      w[N]=0;                 // end of word
      if (N) _generate(N-1);  // generate only if at least one char words ...
      }
  ```

[Notes]

- all the code is in C++
- iteration is usually faster due to no heap trashing if coded properly
- for example these two examples on N=3 the iteration took 2.2s and recursion 2.3s on mine setup
- it took so long because I add every word to VCL TMemo one by one.
- If I created the list in memory myself and copy the whole thing it would be much much faster (68ms instead)
- I could generate the characters from first to last but for that you would also need to know the `N`
- inside recursion so you would need `i,N` as tail which would be much slower
- always try to have as small recursion tail as you can ...
- some language/interpreters/compilers are optimized for recursion and there the recursion is faster then iteration
- in such cases above notes does not apply
- btw if you are clever enough then you can get even rid of `i` in tail and use it as global variable like w
- in that case you have to ensure that before returning from _generate you set `i` to the value it was at its entry point
- something like this:

  ```
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  int i;
  char w[1024]={0};
  void _generate()
      {
      if (i==0) for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++)
          {
          // here w[] contains generated word so do something with it
          }
      else      for (w[i]='a';w[i]<='z';w[i]++)
          {
          i--;
          _generate();
          i++;
          }
      }
  void generate(int N)
      {
      if (N<    0) N=   0;
      if (N>=1024) N=1023;
      w[N]=0;
      i=N-1;
      if (N) _generate();
      }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```
- beware the complexity of this is `O(26^N)` which is huge
- so if `N>4` and poorly coded you can wait a long time till the end ...